# How can I rewrite this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

> The System must be secure:
>
> a. Data encryption.
>   b. User Identification using SIM number and a password.
>   c. User Authentication using verification code.

I think the sentence is not grammatically correct. I don't know how to connect "the system must be secure" with the listed items. I mean that the three situations a, b, and c should be grammatically connected to the main sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add *in regard to*.

> The System must be secure in regard to:
>
> - Data encryption
> - User identification through SIM number, and password
> - User authentication through verification code

Comment: Shouldn't that be "in regard to"?

Comment: I always get confused between _regard of_, and _regard to_. The first seems more natural to me, but I am sure I am wrong about that. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are referring to specific methods by which a system can be secured. If so, perhaps the wording should go something like this:

The System must be secured using one or more of the following methods:

or

The System must be secure. You may use one or more of the following methods to secure the System: